# Xpath of Tags in YouTube Studio

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

What is the Xpath of tags in YouTube Studio Video Editor?

I tried using this but selenium does not recognize this.

```
tag = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="text-input"]').click()
 #tags is a variable storing youtube tags
tag.send_keys(tags)
```

Help me find the Xpath of Tags of YouTube Studio.

Thanks.

Comment: can you share the HTML code?

Comment: @AlinStelian <input id="text-input" autocomplete="off" class="text-input style-scope ytcp-chip-bar" aria-label="Tags" placeholder="Add tag">

Comment: @AlinStelian Please check once on YouTube Studio and check for tags of draft videos.